# type mismatch in prolog code

Tags: prolog

I have written a rule like below:

```
rule_1561_cctype([],_,_,_).
rule_1561_cctype([X1|Y1],[Ru1|Ru1T],[Ru2|Ru2T],[Ru3|Ru3T]):-
    X1 is 0 -> Ru1 in {2,3,4}, Ru2 in {-1}, Ru3 in {-1}
    ;X1 is 1 -> Ru1 in {2,3,4}, Ru2 in {2,3,4}, Ru3 in {-1}
  ;X1 is 2 -> Ru1 in {2}, Ru2 in {2}, Ru3 in {2}
  ;rule_1561_cctype(Y1,Ru1,Ru2,Ru3),!.
```

i am calling this rule like below:

```
rule_1561_cctype(CctypeInt, Ru1, Ru2,Ru3),
```

where CctypeInt is integer list.

but i am getting an error  below:

```
      935      9 Call: rule_1561_cctype(dom(0..2),dom({-1}\/(2..4)),dom({-1}\/(2..4)),dom({-1}\/(2..4))) ? 
! Type error in argument 2 of = /2
! integer expected, but [] found
! goal:  _310957=[]
      935      9 Exception: rule_1561_cctype(dom(0..2),dom({-1}\/(2..4)),dom({-1}\/(2..4)),dom({-1}\/(2..4))) ?
```

am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: Which Prolog are you using?  Is this Visual Prolog perhaps?

Comment: It seems the first argument of `rule_1561_cctype` is expected to be a list.  Butin your call you've passed a term `dom(..)`.  I don't recognize this and could not find it defined in the Sicstus manual.  More critically, your 2nd argument has combined that construct with the  `\/` operator, which is defined as a built-in standard operator to take the bitwise disjunction of two integers.  My guess is that the expression you've given is being parsed as the bitwise negation `\` applied to `/2`, but the latter is not an integer.  Perhaps you need to evaluate these expressions before calling.

Comment: Possibly what you need is to use constraint operators like `#\/` instead of `\/`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing constraint logic programming, right? The problem is that Prolog tries to unify a constrained variable ranging over a numeric with an empty list and reports an error.

Looking at your code I presume that the call to rule_1561_cctype(Y1,Ru1,Ru2,Ru3) should be rule_1561_cctype(Y1,Ru1T,Ru2T,Ru3T).

Comment: Good catch, the tail call almost certainly would need to deal with the tails of the lists.  But the error message seems to point to something happening in the "goal expansion" of the finite domain constraint expressions.  Unfortunately the OP has yet to articulate what you did, that constraint logic programming is involved.